# (Solved) installing mingw for vscode on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, mingw

This problem has been solved

I successfully installed the entirety of MinGW which both my operating system and Vscode seem to recognise, unfortunately when I try and try and compile a project it seems to have issues and I first get an error about g++ not running properly and exiting with code -1

Then I press debug anyway and it fails to create an executable.
If I try and check for errors it says it's fine

what is going on?

EDIT: g++ doesn't seem to run from the command prompt "udenfined reference to 'WinMain"

I'm writing C++ in case it helps

Comment: does MinGW work if you type it all from the command line, if g++ exits with -1 why do you think that debugging will work, read the VSC C++ doc and execute to the letter to get the tutorial working

Comment: Did you use msys2 to install MinGW like the VSCode documentation tells you: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: followed it to the letter until I reached the part about how to write c++, and it seems like the entire program has just stopped working

Comment: ***"udenfined reference to 'WinMain"*** What command line did you use to build? Do you have an `int main()`? Do you have more than 1 source file?

Comment: Ok works now, thanks for the help, added a main()